# strict standards keeping getting this error

Tags: templates

I keep getting this browser errors

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method JSite::getMenu() should not be called statically, 
assuming $this from incompatible context 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\afvidz\templates\videoplus\index.php on line 53`

Strict Standards: Non-static method JApplication::getMenu() should not be called statically, 
assuming $this from incompatible context 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\afvidz\includes\application.php on line 593`
```

and here is my line 53

```
$menu = JSite::getMenu();
```

and line 593

```
$menu = parent::getMenu('site', $options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yoiu are try to call object method in the way static way are (class methods)

```
$object - new JSite;
$menu = $object->getMenu();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `getMenu` like if it was a static method.

You should do :

```
$object = new JSite;             // First you create an object
$menu = $object->getMenu();      // Finally you call getMenu
```

Checkout the documentation to know what is a `static` method : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

**Also this link can be very helpful in your case : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php (checkout the second example).**